# C# Clickable And Transparent Form

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do transparent and clickable form. This form will work full screen. So this form must be clickable. For example if desktop exists behind this form, I must be able to click to folders and open.
If a document exists I must be able to change this document. I couldn't solve how to enable this.
I think it can be done with API codes, but I don't know which API. If you can give me some information/link I will be pleased.

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify what you mean by "clickable and transparent". Attempting to click on any part of a form that is transparent will result in the mouse click going through to whatever is behind that area of the form. You may also want to specify what UI platform you are using - such as WPF or WinForms.

Comment: I want to do as you describe. I'm using Winforms.

Comment: So you want to be able to 'Click-Through' the whole screen? So your application doesn't really need to show a form?? - So what will it do???

Comment: Actually I want to do thing like a screensaver to work night. Lowest standard brightness options of computer still insufficient. So I want to do an adjustable form application. Like this: [link](http://qza21.blogspot.com.tr/2014/10/form.html)

Comment: Maybe set your monitor's brightness a bit lower then. No need for a software solution I think :/...

Comment: I tried what you said, programs like f.lux but screen still bright at dark. So I thought this kind of solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple and works without calling any API function.
But it will prohibit any interaction of your program with the user..
For a Screensaver this makes no sense, however, at least not as you described it. 
The rule is this:

Anything that is not 100% transparent is not click-through.

So you could easily create a darker screen using `Opacity` and a `Black BackColor` but it won't be click-through.

The simplest solution would be to switch between the both modes upon `MouseMove` using a `Timer` to turn the saving mode back on, maybe like this:

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Text = "";
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        switchSaverState(false);
    }

    Point lastMosePosition = Point.Empty;
    int savingWaitMinutes = 10;
    int minute = 60000;
    Timer timer1 = new Timer;

    void switchSaverState(bool saving)
    {
        if (saving)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Black;
            this.Opacity = 0.8;

        }
        else
        {
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Fuchsia;
            this.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;
            this.Opacity = 1;
            timer1.Interval = minute * savingWaitMinutes;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer1.Interval == minute * savingWaitMinutes)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 100;
            switchSaverState(true);
            lastMosePosition = Cursor.Position;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Cursor.Position != lastMosePosition)  { switchSaverState(false); }
        }
    }


    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        lastMosePosition = Cursor.Position;
        switchSaverState(false);
    }
```

But again: This is like a Screensver, meaning that you can't work while it 'saves'! To do that use the controls on your monitor!!